# C# HttpListener 'Bad request' problem

Tags: c#, httplistener, bad-request

For some reason when request is sent to HttpListener via non-standart address it returns

```
<h1>Bad Request (Invalid Hostname)</h1>
```

Example packet:

```
GET /index HTTP/1.1
Host: ::ffff:88.118.32.126:2548
Accept: */*

HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
Content-Type: text/html
Server: Microsoft-HTTPAPI/1.0
Date: Wed, 02 Feb 2011 19:05:18 GMT
Connection: close
Content-Length: 39

<h1>Bad Request (Invalid Hostname)</h1>
```

How could i solve this?

**Edit:**
This is my code

```
public class Server
{
    private HttpListener Listener;
    private Log Log;

    public int Port = 1555;

    public Server(Log _log)
    {
        Log = _log;
    }

    public void Start()
    {
        Listener = new HttpListener();
        Listener.Prefixes.Add(string.Format("http://{0}:{1}/",
            "88.118.32.126", Port));

        Listener.Prefixes.Add(
            string.Format("http://{0}:{1}/",
            "*", Port)); //added these for testing, but still nothing

        Listener.Prefixes.Add(
            string.Format("http://::ffff:{0}:{1}/",
            "*", Port)); //added these for testing, but still nothing

        Listener.Start();
        Listener.BeginGetContext(ProcessRequest, Listener);

        Log.Add(string.Format("HTTP Server started on port {0}",
            Port), LogType.Info, true);
    }

    private void ProcessRequest(IAsyncResult result)
    {
        HttpListener listener = (HttpListener)result.AsyncState;
        HttpListenerContext context = listener.EndGetContext(result);

        HttpListenerRequest request = context.Request;
        HttpListenerResponse response = context.Response;

        string[] UrlParts = request.RawUrl.Split('/');
        Response output;

        if (request.RawUrl == "/index")
            output = new Response(context.Response.OutputStream, 
                ResponseType.Stats, UrlParts, Log);

        response.ContentLength64 = output.Size;
        response.ContentType = output.Header;

        output.Send();

        if (result.IsCompleted)
            Log.Add(String.Format("OUT > {1,15} {0,8} bytes -> {2}",
                output.Size, request.RemoteEndPoint.Address,
                request.RawUrl), LogType.Info, true);

        Listener.BeginGetContext(ProcessRequest, Listener);
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you provide some code? How are you initiating HttpListener?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way this error occurs is when HTTP.SYS can not match the HTTP Host header with its list of valid UrlAcl's. This could be because of problems resolving a hostname.

1. [Related answer explaining configuration steps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4709014/using-custom-domains-with-iis-express/4718029#4718029)
2. [MSDN documentation about setting up HTTP stand-alone](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733768.aspx)
3. [Fixing a “Bad Request (Invalid Hostname)” - 400 Error, on Windows IIS Server](http://www.mrtweak.com/windows-servers/iis-server/fixing-a-bad-request-invalid-hostname-400-error-on-windows-iis/) (relevant potential solutions and commentary)

You can list the mappings at the command line:

[Windows XP Support Tools](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=49ae8576-9bb9-4126-9761-ba8011fabf38) / [2003 Support Tools](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=96a35011-fd83-419d-939b-9a772ea2df90) - `httpcfg`

```
httpcfg query urlacl
```

Included with Windows Vista / 2008 / 7+ - `netsh`

```
netsh http show urlacl
```