# Single sign-on not working correctly using different application pools?

Tags: http, authentication, cookies, iis-7, application-pool

I have found out by creating 2 new websites under IIS 7 that single sign-on authentication doesn't work when run in different application pools. When i move the applications into the same pool i can login on one of them and be logged in on the other one. When i change application pool on one of them, i don't get logged in on the second one.

Is there any settings that can be set in the machine.config file to allow them to share the same cookie over application pools?

---

Ex. 1:
proj1 (app pool .net 2)

proj2 (app pool .net 2)

= Single sign-on works, they are sharing the same auth cookie.

---

Ex. 2:
proj1 (app pool .net 2)

proj2 (app pool .net 4, integrated/classic)

= Single sign-on does not work, they are NOT sharing the same auth cookie.

---

Ex. 2:
proj1 (app pool .net 4, integrated/classic)

proj2 (app pool .net 4, integrated/classic)

= Single sign-on works, they are sharing the same auth cookie.

---

**Original post**

**Latest update at the bottom**

I have 2 projects, one is an asp.net webforms and the other is a mvc 3 project.

I followed this guide, see at the bottom, and i got it working on my computer. But when i upload it to the server, it doesn't work anymore. The differences that i can think of is, 1) on the server we are using SSL, 2) the webforms project is using .net 2 and the MVC project is using .net 4 (integrated mode) and 3) I use IIS 7 on the server and i use VS 2008/2010 to test it on my local machine.

asp.net MVC 3 (.net 4)

```
<forms name=".ASPXAUTH" loginUrl="~/Home/Login" timeout="30" enableCrossAppRedirects="true" domain=".mydomain.com" ticketCompatibilityMode="Framework20" />
```

Webforms (.net 2)

```
<forms name=".ASPXAUTH" loginUrl="Default.aspx" defaultUrl="Default.aspx" timeout="30" domain=".mydomain.com" enableCrossAppRedirects="true" />
```

The funny part is, i uploaded a test.aspx page to both the Mvc (.net 4) and the webforms (.net) project and that just displays some trace.

Both projects have the same sessionid and .ASPXAUTH. On my localhost i can access the ASPXAUTH on the mvc project but i can't access it on the server.

The projects run as subdomains, mvc.mydomain.com and webforms.mydomain.com.

Anyone got any ideas on how to solve this? I have full access to the IIS 7.0.

(I have also tried turning SSL on the server off but i still get the same result)

Guide for authentication sharing:
http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/SingleSignon.aspx

**Updated**
I also tried this: (webforms .net 2.0)

```
var ticket = new FormsAuthenticationTicket(1, "authtest", DateTime.Now, DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(30), false, login.Email);
var enc = FormsAuthentication.Encrypt(ticket);
var cookie = new HttpCookie("authcookie", enc) {Domain = ".mydomain.com"};
Response.Cookies.Add(cookie);
```

and in mvc 3 (.net 4)

```
FormsAuthenticationTicket ticket = FormsAuthentication.Decrypt(HttpContext.Request.Cookies["authcookie"].Value);
ViewBag.User = "User: " + ticket.Name;
```

This throws the following error: "Length of the data to decrypt is invalid."

**Updated 6th jul**

Funny! When i add 2 new domains that runs under .net 2 it works perfectly. But when i change the application pool to .net 4 it stops working. Its like they aren't compatible or i might be missing a setting somewhere

Comment: Is the server site load balanced ?

Comment: I'm not able to get it working on my 2 MVC4 web applications in the same pool. What settings I need to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We could not find any ways of doing this so we had to convert our other project to use the .net 4 integrated app pool.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to set the machineKey in the Web.config of both application to the same value. You can generate a machinekey section here: http://aspnetresources.com/tools/machineKey

Comment: They are the same, i triple checked that.

Comment: ok another try. Set the domain to mydomain.com and not .mydomain.com

Comment: Have you tried setting up different domains in IIS Express (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4709014/using-custom-domains-with-iis-express) to replicate the problem locally?

Comment: I have added 2 new domains in the IIS 7. Going to try with them first to see if i can get them to work. If that doesn't work then ill try it with IIS express.

Comment: Funny! When i add 2 new domains that runs under .net 2 it works perfectly. But when i change the application pool to .net 4 it stops working. Its like they aren't compatible or i might be missing a setting somewhere.