# Using IIS Express with a team - when not using localhost

Tags: visual-studio, iis-express

I assume we must be missing a trick as we are finding using IIS Express with teams quite painful.

The issue is IIS Express' applicationhost.config is stored locally in each persons MyDocuments folder, and thus separate to the Visual Studio solution and not in source control.

So when we make a change everyone has to manually update applicationhost.config on their machine.

THe update visual studio does to the applicationhost.config file fails, because we are not using localhost, [we have host entries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4709014/using-custom-domains-with-iis-express) to give our environments different names.

[image: The local IIS URL specifed for web project has not been configured.]

[image: Creation of the virtual directory You must specify "localhost" for the server name]

Is there a better way?

Answer (score 2):

[Refer to Here](http://johan.driessen.se/posts/Accessing-an-IIS-Express-site-from-a-remote-computer)

> UPDATE FOR VISUAL STUDIO 2015: As was pointed out to me in a comment
>   by Søren Nielsen, in Visual Studio 2015 the IIS Express configuration
>   files have moved. They are now separate per project, and stored in
>   /{project folder}/.vs/config/applicationhost.config. Which is much
>   better, in my opinion, just don't forget to add .vs/ to your
>   .gitignore/.hgignore files!

Other wise **NO** there is no better way. Instead of IIS Express, for remote access you can use IIS on your development machine...

Answer (score -4):

It doesn't seem a big deal: when you load a project configured to run with IIS express, VS checks your applicationhost.config for that entry. If it doesn't find it, it just prompts you with the problem and asks you if you want it to create it for you. Just click "yes" and the entry is added.

At least, that's how we deal with that here. The problem is just the first time anyway, all other settings are stored in web.config in the project, which is versioned, so everything should be smooth.