# IIS Express + Visual Studio 2010 + non-local Project Url

Tags: visual-studio-2010, iis-express

I am facing a dilemma related to [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4709014/using-custom-domains-with-iis-express) but not exactly the same.

I want to use IIS Express with a custom URL but **without modifying the local HOSTS file.**

Specifically, for me, `dev.example.com` resolves to 127.0.0.1 using DNS (our DNS is set up so that `*.example.com` resolves to 127.0.0.1). This is what I want to use as a project URL. If I add `dev.example.com` to my HOSTS file, it works, but if I don't, it doesn't. I'm *guessing* this is because Visual Studio doesn't recognize this as being a local URL.

Is there a way to not modify the HOSTS file but still use a custom URL like `dev.example.com` as a Project Url in Visual Studio with IIS Express?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes-sortof. `IISExpress` configuration is stored in the executing users profile under:

```
C:\Users\<username>\Documents\IISExpress\config\
```

You'll need to edit **applicationhost.xml**

Locate the `<sites>` section and extend:

```
        <site name="WebApplication1" id="20">
            <application path="/" applicationPool="Clr4IntegratedAppPool">
                <virtualDirectory path="/" physicalPath="C:\inetpub\WebApplication1" />
            </application>
            <bindings>
                <binding protocol="http" bindingInformation="*:45965:localhost" />                  
                <binding protocol="http" bindingInformation="*:80:dev.example.com" />
            </bindings>
        </site>
```

Note that the port 80 must not be occupied by IIS in case it's running on your dev box.

The problem that this solution is facing, that with these settings pressing F5 in VS, or otherwise start the website from VS will ALWAYS want to start on localhost, and will not initialize the other binding. You have to start IISExpress manually with the following:

c:\Program Files (x86)\IIS Express\iisexpress.exe" /site:`WebApplication1`

Comment: Thank you very much, that last thing (start IIS manually) solved everything for me.