# Using Custom Domains With IIS Express and a website project

Tags: web-config, asp.net-4.0

I found this great thread [Using Custom Domains With IIS Express](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4709014/using-custom-domains-with-iis-express) on how to configure a web application project to use a custom domain like example.com instead of localhost:1234. But how do I do this for a website project?

I don't how how to set 'Override Applicationroot URL'.  I set the start URL to http://example.com:1234, but I still receive HTTP Error 400. The request hostname is invalid.