# VS Express 2013 for Web - debugging on machine's IP Address not localhost avgnsa 100% CPU

Tags: asp.net, debugging, antivirus

I am using VS Express 2013 for Web and debugging a website using the machine's IP Address on the LAN rather than localhost in order to more easily debug activity from another device on the LAN.

avgnsa.exe consistently takes approaching 100% CPU during this activity (even when the page is just sat there and I am making no http calls) and consistently more or less disappears when I stop.

I am having difficulty finding any useful information from AVG Forum and wondered if someone had experienced this before.  I'm thinking I may have to tell avg to ignore some particular debug process or something but if this is the case I am not sure what the name of that process would be.

Comment: Can you add an exception for your process in AVG?

Comment: OK, bit dumb/newbie, I'm unsure what the actual process would be?  My browser?  Or what ever the cut down lite web server process is called?  I don't think it's iis is it, when you launch in debug? Some small temp debug type web server right?  Maybe I should watch for the process when I post a page?  Any one know what process it would be?

Comment: I see VWDExpress.exe taking cpu now and again but I guess that's just the IDE?  I need the path but can't see how to get that from resource manager.  Found one in C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE .

Comment: using this method [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14725455/connecting-to-visual-studio-debugging-iis-express-server-over-the-lan) after I launch in debug, it still launches the site under localhost, but I can change localhost to the machine ip address and debugging works fine.  However avgnsa and chrome together take 100% cpu.  I have added avg exceptions for VWDExpress.exe and iisexpress.exe but nothing changes.  If I turn off avgnsa there are still to instances of chrome.exe which together continuously take 50% cpu.   This is with no other tabs or windows and without making posts.

Comment: Is there a bug in your code causing this? Spinning thread or something?

Comment: One should never rule that out of course.  But I launch no additional threads, everything goes on in the handling of the post and lots of activity while running on localhost takes little CPU.  This occurs with no posting.

Answer (score 0):

I experienced the same problem and finally figured out that the *AVG Link Scanner* is causing this issue.

You can read more about this problem in the [AVG forum](https://forums.avg.com/us-en/avg-forums?sec=thread&act=show&id=29617).

I tried to define a bunch of exceptions in *AVG* for all VS-related and project-related folders/files, however, it seems like the *Link Scanner* module completely ignores those exceptions.

I ended up disabling *AVG Link Scanner* (you will not miss it) which finally solved the problem:

1. Open *AVG* from system tray
2. Click on the *Web* item
3. Disable *Link Scanner*