# How to connect client to Visual Studio 2017 IIS over LAN

Tags: asp.net, iis, visual-studio-2017

This is a duplicate. Except that the answers for the other questions (see links at the end) don't make it work for me. And none mention VS 2017 except for the odd comment - perhaps that's the difference?

I've looked at a load of information, and I think all resolve down to:

- netsh http add urlacl
- open up the firewall
- add binding to applicationhost.config
- Run VS as administrator

I've done that. About 50 times. I've disabled the firewall completely. I've tried loads of combinations of netsh (where 44362 is my https port for the site and 60559 is normal):

```
 - netsh http add urlacl https://*:44362/  
 - netsh http add urlacl http://*:44362/  
 - netsh http add urlacl http://*:60559/  
 - netsh http add urlacl https://192.168.0.5:44362/  
 - netsh http add urlacl https://machinename:44362/
```

I've tried quite a few bindings, but the most reliable is this - which is what I currently have:

```
    <bindings>
        <binding protocol="http" bindingInformation="*:60559:" />
        <binding protocol="https" bindingInformation="*:44362:" />
    </bindings>
```

This is what my netsh is currently set to, and it allows localhost through:

```
Reserved URL            : http://*:60559/
    User: \Everyone
        Listen: Yes
        Delegate: No
        SDDL: D:(A;;GX;;;WD)

Reserved URL            : https://*:44362/
    User: \Everyone
        Listen: Yes
        Delegate: No
        SDDL: D:(A;;GX;;;WD)
```

I'm testing it by trying to connect using the IP using both of:
`http://192.168.0.5:60559`
and
`https://192.168.0.5:44362`

But the client just says "connection refused". With the firewall off.

So I guess my question is: **What am I missing???**

(Here are a couple of questions I've tried the answers to):
 - [Connecting to Visual Studio debugging IIS Express server over the lan](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14725455/connecting-to-visual-studio-debugging-iis-express-server-over-the-lan)
 - [Using Custom Domains With IIS Express](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4709014/using-custom-domains-with-iis-express)