# android sending post request always returns 400 even with correct json string

Tags: java, android, httpclient

So I am trying to send a post request to my api using the code below.
When i try the request in fiddler it works. But in android I always get a 400 error.

```
        String url = "http://192.168.1.105:17443/NewUser";
        URL obj = new URL(url);
        HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) obj.openConnection();

        con.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=UTF-8");

        con.setDoInput(true);
        con.setDoOutput(true);
        con.setRequestMethod("POST");

        DataOutputStream os = new DataOutputStream(con.getOutputStream());
        String test = user.toJson().toString();
        os.writeBytes(test);
        os.close();

        int responseCode = con.getResponseCode();
```

Comment: It would be helpful to know what `user` is and what `toJson()` does.

Comment: is the server giving you any error description? i.e. print `con.getErrorStream()`  as string - "400 Bad Request" is only semi useful. Sidenote: if you actually want to ensure you send `charset=UTF-8`, don't do writeBytes, but something based on `test.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the error I received was a invalid hostname.

I needed to modify my api to allow requests that were not coming from localhost.

you can find more information here:
[Connecting to Visual Studio debugging IIS Express server over the lan](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14725455/connecting-to-visual-studio-debugging-iis-express-server-over-the-lan)