# Connecting to .NETCore 3 app from Visual Studio for Mac over LAN

Tags: visual-studio, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, visual-studio-mac

I am trying to access a MVC web app built with .NETCore framework on Visual Studio for Mac over the local wifi.

For Windows, the related question is:

[Connecting to Visual Studio debugging IIS Express server over the lan](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14725455/connecting-to-visual-studio-debugging-iis-express-server-over-the-lan)

Edit: This is for the Debug mode of Visual Studio

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not possible in the current implementation of VS.

However, VS comes with `live share` feature. This way the host machine can share the port with the live-shared machine(s) and it can be debugged on any machine.

Answer (score 0):

In a browser you should call IP address (.Net Core computer) with a port. For example: `http://10.0.0.1:5000`.

Comment: This doesn't work. The port is not open by default in .Net Core. I should add this is in Debug mode in the Visual Studio