# Connect to ASP.NET Core hosted server with different machine on same LAN

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, iis, ngrok

On running my ASP.NET Core web application, I was able to do desired works. 
I wanted to to do the same using different machine on same LAN using `<ip-address>:<port-number>/` 
I tried to modify my `applicationhost.config` seeing this post [Connecting to Visual Studio debugging IIS Express server over the lan](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14725455/connecting-to-visual-studio-debugging-iis-express-server-over-the-lan) but no luck.

```
 <site name="WebSite1" id="1" serverAutoStart="true">
        <application path="/">
          <virtualDirectory path="/" physicalPath="%IIS_SITES_HOME%\WebSite1" />
        </application>
        <bindings>
          <binding protocol="http" bindingInformation="*:8080:" />
        </bindings>
      </site>
```

File path was `(solutionFolder)\.vs\config`

Tried bindingInformation with `bindingInformation=":8080:*"`  
I have disabled my firewall as well.
I am trying to get this done on Visual Studio 2017.

I tried to use ngrok to tunnel my localhost as well.

Any help?

`This seems to be like an error connecting to http://<ip-address>:<port-number>. The response status was 0` getting this when using from different system.

Ping is working.

Comment: What results do you get from cmd.exe >Ping localhost?  Different machines are configured differently for local host.  Some give loopback 127.0.0.1 others give the IP address.  There is a host file C:\Windows\System32\Drivers\etc\hosts that configures the localhost.  Port numbers above 1000 are not normally blocked so I do not think that is the issue.  It may be the server want https (secure) and you are sending just http.  What error are you getting.  Responses should be 200 OK,  Error are a different results and knowing the error number helps determine the issue.

Comment: At least you need to show your changes to `applicationHost.config` and its file path. If you edit a wrong file at the wrong place, it won't work.

Comment: @LexLi updated with config file where I made changes. Any help

Comment: @jdweng Reply from ::1: time, with 0% loss is coming.

Comment: If you are getting a response than what is the issue?  Did you look at the response.  If the data in the response is wrong than you request is the issue.

Comment: Sorry for not being clear... Here with reply I meant ping localhost which you asked me to do @jdweng

Comment: Conveyor, mentioned in your linked post, didn't help?

Comment: Unfortunately no, solution there was for VS 2013 not for VS 2017 @JimWsaysreinstateMonica

Comment: @HarshRaj for 2015/2017/2019 see https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=vs-publisher-1448185.ConveyorbyKeyoti