# How to use domain name instead of localhost in IIS Express

Tags: visual-studio-2012, iis-express

I am developing an ASP.Net MVC 4 website on VS 2012 which runs on IIS Express.
While running my website locally, I would like to see `data.xyz.com` instead of `localhost/Data` in the browser address bar.
I have followed few other questions on SO, mainly [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4709014/using-custom-domains-with-iis-express). But when I run the project, it says `Unable to launch the IIS Express Web server.Port '80' is in use.`

So for time being, I am using port 8080 to get it to work, which I dont want to. How do I fix this?

Update: More info:
netstat data on port 80

```
TCP    0.0.0.0:80             0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING
TCP    [::]:80                [::]:0                 LISTENING
```

Can not obtain ownership information for either of the processes.

Comment: Does this help?: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4709014/using-custom-domains-with-iis-express?lq=1

Comment: Thats the one I linked in my question. But couldn't go further as I was getting `port 80 in use` error message.

Comment: Ah sorry missed the link when I first read that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was SSRS which was listening on port 80. Had to turn off that process to run my app on port 80.

Answer (score 0):

You should find who is using port 80, I guess you also have full IIS installed? 
Try to just open `http://localhost:80` and see who will respond on this request.

Comment: Check Skype, from some version it started to use 80 and 443 ports for incoming connection. Tools->Options->Advanced->Connection.

Comment: I get the same error after I changed port numbers and even after quitting it.

Comment: btw, you can run "netstat -o" to see who is using your 80 / 443 ports.

Comment: @outcoldman Thanks for the Skype hint. This error was killing me and Skype was the knife.