# Custom URL for RESTful Web Service using Visual Studio 2012

Tags: web-services, rest, url-routing

I have created a RESTful web service application using Visual Studio 2012. I would like to access this web service using the custom URL instead of `http://localhost:Port` or `http://localhost/Test`. I had followed the steps mentioned in the below URL, but that did not work for me.
[Using Custom Domains With IIS Express](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4709014/using-custom-domains-with-iis-express)

Modified WCF Application Project by going to Properties -> Web, then set Use IIS Express -> Project to "`http://localhost/54077`" and Override Applicationroot URL to "`http://dev.test.com/enroll`". Hit "Create Virtual Directory"

Modified the C:\Users\<>\Documents\IISExpress\config\applicationhost.config as below:

```
<bindings>
  <binding protocol="http" bindingInformation="*:54077:localhost" />
  <binding protocol="http" bindingInformation="*:80:dev.test.com"/>
</bindings>
```

Added the below line to C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts

```
127.0.0.1 dev.test.com
localhost dev.test.com
```

When I ran the WS service from Visual Studio 2012, I get error as "Unable to Launch the IIS Express Web Server. Port 80 in use".

Does anybody knows answer to this issue?

Also I would like to know how to configure the web service with custom URI using
- With Use IIS Express Unchecked
- With Use IIS Express checked

Thanks advance

Comment: 80 is default port and is in use by iis page, try changing the port

Comment: Changed the port in applicationhost.config as below:
<bindings>
  <binding protocol="http" bindingInformation="*:54077:localhost" />
  <binding protocol="http" bindingInformation="*:8080:dev.test.com"/>
</bindings>

Which results the error "Unable to launch the IIS Express Web Server. The Start URL specified is not valid"

Answer (score 0):

Try it with only one Binding element. Maybe every Binding forces a new instance of the IIS so when the first one is started, then the second one can't listen on port 80.

It's the same like you run Skype and Apache ;)

Comment: Trying with only one Binding element did not solve the problem.