# Unable to change IP address in IIS Express

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2008, iis-express

I previously configured IIS express server to the IP address `192.168.1.4` for a certain project. I did this by changing the `applicationhost.config` file to so:

```
<bindings>
    <binding protocol="http" bindingInformation=":8080:192.168.1.4" />
 </bindings>
```

I now need to change the IP address to `192.168.1.5`. After changing the `applicationhost.config` and opening Visual Studio, I get the following error:

Creation of the virtual directory `http://192.168.1.4:8080` failed with the error: Cannot create the Web site `http://192.168.1.4:8080`. You must specify "localhost" for the server name.

Can anyone tell me how to fix this error so I can change the IP address? I am using Visual Studio Express 2013

Comment: Fix what? Is `192.168.1.5` address assigned to one of network cards on you machine?

Comment: That is currently my machine's IP Address on the LAN, I want this to be accessible from other machines on the Network, which is why I'm not using default settings.

Comment: Yes, IIS Express will not listen for external connections. There are many similar questions like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4709014/using-custom-domains-with-iis-express ... consider if you can use normal IIS on your version of Windows instead.

Comment: I"m getting an error when try to 'Create Virtual Directory', neither of the suggestions make sence to me, IIS is not running and I do not have port 80 selected anywhere in my settings file.