# Using private IP address for accessing Web API service in Visual Studio 2013

Tags: asp.net, .net, visual-studio, binding, visual-studio-2013

I developed a Web API service, and now I'm trying to test it (inside IIS Express in Visual Studio 2013). It works good, but I can use only the address:

```
http://localhost:62576
```

Instead of localhost I want use my private IP address (192.168.1.2)

Searching others stackoverflow questions I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5186680/1584654) . So I have modified the config file, the line:

```
<binding protocol="http" bindingInformation="*:62576:localhost" />
```

into

```
<binding protocol="http" bindingInformation="*:62576:*" />
```

But I have always the same error, when I try to call the service using my private IP address:

```
HTTP Error 400. The request hostname is invalid.
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using the `127.0.0.1` local IP. This is a loop-back to your own machine, but might work. Should you call it with that IP it might just solve the translation error.

`http://localhost:62576` can be changed to `http://127.0.0.1:62576`

Hope it might help!

(thanks for the correction Joseph, I was thinking home setup not machine).

Comment: 192.168.1.1 is not a loopback address. The loopback address is 127.0.0.1