# How do I stop Skype from using HTTP or HTTPS ports 80 and 443?

Tags: webserver, port, skype

I installed the Apache web server on my Windows 7 machine and I'm unable to start it because Skype.exe is already using HTTP port 80 and HTTPS port 443.

[image: Skype ports]

I need Apache and Skype to co-exist on the same machine. How do I configure Apache to use other ports, or prevent Skype from listening on these ports?

Comment: Haha. Micorosft sometimes does funny things. Image if all of the applications wanted to do the same!

Comment: That is **NOT** funny, it is thoughtless

Comment: "Questions about general computing hardware and software are off-topic for Stack Overflow unless they directly involve tools used primarily for programming." ) 
Actually, it does.

Comment: @Yoshiya I think he meant funny as in "strange" not funny as in "hilarious"

Answer (score 236, accepted):

To turn off and disable Skype usage of and listening on port 80 and port 443, open the Skype window, then click on the **Tools** menu and select **Options**. Click on the **Advanced** tab, and go to the **Connection** sub-tab. **Untick** or **uncheck** the checkbox for `Use port 80 and 443 as an alternative for additional incoming connections` option. Click on the Save button and then restart Skype to make the change effective.

Comment: @Venkatesh  Skype is known for his great Firewall penetrating abillity and much more. If Skype is not able to find an open Port it will try to use port 80. Cause…
In 99% of Company Infrastructures and Homeoffices Port 80 is open for Browsers on the Router, Firewall, etc... And that is the easiest way to go for Skype. Skype ignores what application it blocks.

Comment: For *outbound* connections it's true that most devices will allow connections *to* 80/443, but for *inbound* connections, most Firewall/NAT devices will either block 80/443 or redirect to their own web server.  So, it doesn't explain why Skype would need to *listen* on those ports... they say alternative connections but presumably it can use the existing *outbound* connection it created for communications...

Comment: Thank you thank you. This has been extremely annoying forever! I should also mention that on the same page you can set a single port to use so that you can use simplify (and possibly secure better) your firewall rules.

Comment: It makes sense -- I guess they figure most of their users don't have their own web servers running -- but still, doesn't it seem a tiny bit anti-social to automatically take over ports 80/443? What if every other app out there decided to do the same thing? Will apps now go out and try to change the startup order so they can get to grab port 80 first? Thanks for the pointer to fix it @JelloDude.

Comment: There is no tools -> advanced in the new skype

Comment: @MasterYoda, exactly the problem I have right now. Can't find that setting.

Comment: Apparently it's not possible with new Skype --> https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/skype/forum/skype_win10-skype_messms-skype_instamessms/how-to-change-default-port-in-new-skype/41d6d928-e1f9-4c2d-b318-94a9f7daa0ab  .... shame on you Microsoft. S.H.A.M.E