# ASP .NET Core 2.0 Change "localhost" to a "hostname"

Tags: asp.net-mvc, binding, hostname

I have a Web App written based on MVC framework. It runs really well on the localhost and default port 51290. Now I need to run it using my domain name e.g. myhostname. What I have tried is to add a line in "applicationhost.config"  section:

```
            <binding protocol="http" bindingInformation="*:80:myhostname" />
```

When I press Ctr+F5, I got an error msg saying port 80 is in use.

The server is IIS express.

Can someone please instruct how should I run this App using host name? Thanks.

Comment: If you use Skype, it could be that using port 80. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22994888/why-skype-using-http-or-https-ports-80-and-443)

Answer (score 1):

After I run visual studio as admin, everything worked!

Answer (score -1):

Win+R to open the Run dialog.and type "drivers"

now you can see "etc" folder,inside that there is a file named as "hosts".open that and change local host name to your domain name.
http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/8d44fb/how-to-access-the-site-using-domain-name-instead-of-localhos/

Comment: Ohh...Sorry john..it was a mistake.i dont know why i answered like this...extreamly sorry.