# Mapping multiple domains on localhost to single MVC app

Tags: asp.net-mvc, localhost, iis-express

Is it possible to map multiple domains  to a single MVC app, deployed with IIS Express on Localhost?

Ideally I would like to use a wildcard or regex type mapping, something like: (`http://my[a-zA-Z]website.com`).  That would mean the app would run for all the examples below:

- mylovelywebsite.com
- mygreatwebsite.com
- myspiffingwebsite.com

I have been following [these instructions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5186680/1778169) for mapping domains to localhost, but I have no idea how to approach mapping multiple/wildcard domains.

Is it possible?

**Update**

20 hours later and I don't think it is possible. I tried using the * as a wildcard letter but I couldn't get it to work. Eventually I just manually typed in all 200 domains :(.

If I'm wrong, please leave an answer below, because it would be good to know for future reference.