# Why does SSL 443 fail to work in IIS Express for custom domains of Visual Studio web projects?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, iis-express

I have VS2013 set up with IIS Express to use a custom domain as follows:

```
http://mydomain.local
https://mydomain.local
```

The port 80 url works great, the port 443 does not (**Bad Request**, Page Cannot Be Displayed, aka site doesn't exist).

**Why?**

Clearly IIS Express is struggling to map or use port 443 with this name, but why?

**applicationhost.config:**

```
  <site name="MyDomain" id="16">
      <application path="/" applicationPool="Clr4IntegratedAppPool">
          <virtualDirectory path="/" physicalPath="C:\Projects\MyDomain" />
      </application>
      <bindings>
          <binding protocol="http" bindingInformation="*:80:MyDomain.local" />
          <binding protocol="https" bindingInformation="*:443:MyDomain.local" />
      </bindings>
  </site>
```

**hosts file:**

```
127.0.0.1   MyDomain.local
```

**VS Project Properties:**

Start Url, Project Url, and Override application root URL are all `https://MyDomain.local`.

Clicking `Create Virtual Directory` results in NO errors because it is happy with the config in applicationhosts.config.

NOTE: with the above settings alone, `http://mydomain.local` (port 80) works fine!

Further, looking at the properties window on the project node, all settings are as expected:

```
SSL Enabled: True
SSL URL:     https://mydomain.local 
URL:         http://mydomain.local
```

Also, looking at IIS Express in the task bar, these show up as expected for 443 and 80 respectively.

**Going Ninja:**

It should not be necessary (seems how http:// works without doing this), but I ran netsh for this just to be sure the URL is registered:

```
netsh http add urlacl url=https://MyDomain.local:443/ user=Everyone
```

This of course results in an error "... already exists". So then I run:

```
netstat -o
  TCP    127.0.0.1:80           mydomain:2063      ESTABLISHED     4
  TCP    127.0.0.1:2063         mydomain:http      ESTABLISHED     2276
  ...
```

I see nothing camping on port 443. No, Skype is not installed on this machine! (a supposedly common issue).

I am at a total loss.  What the heck?  This is not rocket science.

**Environment:**

- Windows 10
- VS 2013 Update 5 (running as admin)

**Other Info:**

I have researched this like crazy.  Many articles on Stack Overflow and elsewhere. Here are just a couple of prime ones:

[Using Custom Domains With IIS Express](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4709014/using-custom-domains-with-iis-express)

and
http://www.hanselman.com/blog/WorkingWithSSLAtDevelopmentTimeIsEasierWithIISExpress.aspx

I have tried everything I can see that is logical to do. For the issue I am raising, the resolution is to set all the settings I just described. Since that doesn't work, it warrants a post of its own!

What am I missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on the linked blog below, you need to bind a certificate to port 443. IIS Express has already bound ports 44300 to 44399 to a local certificate for local https development.

I have not tried it, but (the bottom section of) this blog shows how you can bind to port 443 the existing local certificate IISExpress uses for ports 44300 to 44399.

[Run IISExpress on port 443 using SSL and wildcard subdomains](http://benjii.me/2014/11/run-iis-express-on-port-443-using-ssl-and-wildcard-subdomains/)

Comment: Yep, I botched that.  I was too focused on the browser/client.  I knew the browser would throw an error without a valid cert, but I did not consider the server refusing to serve up the site without it. I was planning to do the cert last after I knew things were working, but it is of course part of the initial setup. Thanks!