# IIS Express with SSL and friendly name

Tags: ssl, iis-express

I set up my localhost site for my project following this procedure:
https://www.hanselman.com/blog/WorkingWithSSLAtDevelopmentTimeIsEasierWithIISExpress.aspx

My applicationhost.config looks like this:

```
    <site name="ProjectName.Web" id="2">
        <application path="/" applicationPool="Clr4IntegratedAppPool">
            <virtualDirectory path="/" physicalPath="C:\Users\myUserName\Source\Repos\SolutionName\ProjectName.Web" />
        </application>
        <bindings>
            <binding protocol="http" bindingInformation="*:51415:localhost" />
            <binding protocol="https" bindingInformation="*:44342:localhost" />
            <binding protocol="http" bindingInformation="*:80:myPC.myDomain.com" />
            <binding protocol="https" bindingInformation="*:443:myPC.myDomain.com" />
        </bindings>
    </site>
```

I reviewed this post also: [Why does SSL 443 fail to work in IIS Express for custom domains of Visual Studio web projects?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33336370/why-does-ssl-443-fail-to-work-in-iis-express-for-custom-domains-of-visual-studio)

Still get this:

> This site can’t be reached
>
> The connection was reset.

How can I debug this issue?

Comment: What's the URL in your browser when you see the error? Run SSLDiag for your IIS Express site in Jexus Manager and see if it reveals the issue, https://www.jexusmanager.com/en/latest/tutorials/ssl-diagnostics.html