# Default routing to Project URL in an ASP.MVC Application

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, iis-express

I am testing `SSL` Encryption on my local PC which requires me to change my ASP.MVC `Project URL` from `http://localhost:xxxx` to something like `http://payroll.net:81`. 
When I run this application, ASP.MVC is probably not loading the project on this URL. Browser is giving the following error:

> The server at payroll.net can't be found, because the DNS lookup failed. DNS is the network service that translates a website's name to its Internet address. This error is most often caused by having no connection to the Internet or a misconfigured network. It can also be caused by an unresponsive DNS server or a firewall preventing Google Chrome from accessing the network.

I have to mention that I have updated `hosts` file in `../WINDOWS/System32/drivers/etc/` location as:

127.0.0.1 payroll.net:81.

I also have to mention that if I run the same project under default `Project URL` that `IISExpress` uses i.e., `http://localhost:xxxx`, project runs all good. Any idea on how this project can be run with `http://payroll.net:81` URL on IISExpress?

Comment: hosts file can't map port to host. So it is better if you change `http://localhost:xxxx` to `https://localhost:xxxx` without changing host file and then open `https://localhost:xxxx`

Comment: @AbdulRaufMujahid So its better if I change `localhost:xxxx` to `localhost:xxxx` ???

Comment: @RehanKhan just be sure your port isnt using already.

Comment: @RehanKhan yes change `http://localhost:xxxx` to `https://localhost:yyyy`

Comment: useful information check this out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4709014/using-custom-domains-with-iis-express

Comment: @Zergling Good point, but no. Because if port is in use, MS Visual Studio will throw an error because IISExpress will complain it about the port-in-use problem and won't start.

Comment: @Zergling Thank you for the link mate.

Comment: @RehanKhan, do you want to run your project under `https`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

hosts file can't resolve IP addresses to hostname if port is specified with the IP address. So

`127.0.0.1 payroll.net:81` is wrong

and

`127.0.0.1 payroll.net` is correct

Now you can safely open https://payroll.net:81. (which now automatically maps to https://localhost:81) Just make sure the site is hosted on IISExpress on port 81 and ssl is enabled

### Additional Notes:

The point I wanted to demonstrate in my first comment was that SSL testing does not require you to change your url from http://localhost:xxxx to https://payroll.net:81 (As mentioned in your question). For SSL testing. you can just host your site to any different unused port without changing hosts file e.g https://localhost:91

### Source:

My comments and their verification in Rehan Khan's answer

Comment: One can also learn that ports are not to be configured in the `dns alias file` (`hosts`) and they are to be configured only on IISExpress (or any other equivalent server) and in your application.  So `dns alias file` function is to only resolves ip addresses to hostnames. Opening and closing of ports is application server's job. (Server-Client Architecture). `IISExpress` being the `Server` and our `MS Visual Studio Application` as `Client`.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to run your web application using `https`, just add the attribute '[RequireHttps]' to your controllers.

If you have two controllers called `HomeController.cs` and `ActionController.cs`, then add this attribute to both the controllers like,

```
[RequireHttps]
public class HomeController : BaseController
{
// Your controller
}
```

So, when you make a call to the action inside the `HomeController` it forces the browser to use `https`.

Comment: do you mean `[RequireHttps]` rather than `[RequireHttp]`? Please correct it in your code if thats true.

Comment: @RehanKhan, Yes, it is `RequireHttps` not `RequireHttp`.

Answer (score 0):

With the help from @AbdulRaufMujahid comments, I've managed to solve out the issue and will answer my own question.

`hosts` file in `C:\WINDOWS\System32\driver\etc\` directory doesn't resolve `IP` addresses to `hostname` if `port` is specified with the `IP` address. As in my case:

127.0.0.1 payroll.net:**81** *------> is wrong ----- > specifying port number 81 prevents the resolution of `127.0.0.1`(**IP**) to `payroll.net`(**hostname**).*

As soon as I removed `81` as:

127.0.0.1 payroll.net ------> *is correct*

Project started running like a charm. :-) Thank you @AbdulRaufMujahid and everyone who helped.