# Is it possible to run an IIS Express instance with a recognised SSL certificate?

Tags: ssl, .net-core, lets-encrypt

I'm having an issue with my development where I am trying to implement OAuth authentication in my app.  In order to get this to work I have to set up my .net core app to run with SSL certificates.  These certificates are generated automatically and trusted, so far so good.

The issue arises where I try to use a phone client on these sites.  Obviously the device doesn't have the certificate installed, and installing the certificate on the device makes little difference (the certificate provided by the dotnet tool doesn't have a CA attribute or something? So I can't physically trust the certificate on an iOS device).

From where I'm standing, it would make more sense to just use a Let's Encrypt SSL certificate on IIS Express, have the certificate provided by a recognised authority, but it seems that I can't do that for localhost.  I think this is because the Let's Encrypt ACME bot can't connect to my local development instance which makes sense.

Is there any way to have a recognised development certificate (when I say recognised, I mean something like Let's Encrypt) in use for IIS express or local development?  Or do I have to use a self signed certificate and find some way to install them on my testing devices?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need 2 steps to achieve it.

1. Configure your IIS Express to use a custom domain name rather than localhost. This custom domain name is the one that you have SSL certificate for. Check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4709014/using-custom-domains-with-iis-express) for how to do it.
2. Bind the Let's Encrypt certificate to IIS Express. [This blog post](https://dillieodigital.wordpress.com/2016/04/12/soup-to-nuts-custom-domains-and-ssl-in-iis-express/) uses a self signed cert, but in theory it should also work for Let's Encrypt cert.

Comment: Blog post mentioned above was very useful.