# how to configure fiddler to monitor wcf calls to a wcf services hosted in IISExpress

Tags: wcf, fiddler, iis-express

situation:

my website (which contains the WCF service) is hosted in IISExpres port number 58366 (http://localhost:58366/myapp)

I have a winforms client which connects to the wcf service using BasicHttpBinding

I want to debug my wcf calls using fiddler, but can't seem find how to redirect wcf calls through fiddler.

Answer (score 6):

IISExpress idiotically binds to the hostname "localhost", not just to the port, so conventional workarounds as with adding a dot to the hostname don't work. Solution seems to be **[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4706468/using-fiddler-with-iis7-express)**. Note the last part of the selected answer: Use "localhost.fiddler" and Fiddler will emit "localhost" when proxying.

Answer (score 2):

Rick Strahl has a good article on this here: http://www.west-wind.com/weblog/posts/2009/Jan/14/Monitoring-HTTP-Output-with-Fiddler-in-NET-HTTP-Clients-and-WCF-Proxies

Pretty sure a winforms app will usually pick up the default system proxy as set by fiddler.  Are you operating on `localhost`?  Try connecting to your machine name.

Comment: IIS express shouldn't be a factor, as you want to configure the winforms app to talk via fiddler.

Comment: IIS Express binds to the "localhost" hostname, not just the loopback adapter at 127.0.0.1. It is a misconfiguration out of the box. The Visual Studio Web Development Server (Cassini) as well as IIS both handle your scenario fine; but not IIS Express.