# Is localhost not saved anymore in "App Domain"?

Tags: facebook, dns

In the App configuration on Facebook, I was able to save "localhost" as App Domain for my local testing while building the page.
Now after typing localhost - it is just not saved. other domains are saved with no problem.

Any idea?

Is local testing option had ended?
What other option do we have?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://dyn.com/dns/dyndns-free/

Use `DynDNS` service so you can access your computer (`localhost`) from internet via domain eg `ltye.dyndns.org`

> Dyn’s legendary free DNS service allows you to create a hostname that
>   points to your home or office IP address, providing a easy URL for you
>   to remember anywhere you have internet access.

Make sure you download DynDNS client http://dyn.com/support/clients/ so that your IP is synchronized automatically with DynDNS service.

Comment: This answers the second part of the question, with a very original thought. So thank you. Does it mean that localhost is really not an option by facebook anymore?

Comment: @ltye, thanks, unfortunately, I never used that option so I can't tell you for sure. Either way I think that this solution is better (at least that is my experience). Cheers.

Comment: Also only works if you have a fixed ip address with your internet provider- at least in the Netherlands that is usually not the case without paying extra, not sure how it is elsewhere.

Comment: @scott that is not true, whole point is to be dynamic... you have to download Updater http://dyn.com/support/clients/ which updates your IP on DynDNS everytime it is changed. Some routers have that option too.

Answer (score 2):

As you in the attached image, localhost working perfectly:

Plush I tested app configured for localhost: https://apps.facebook.com/myapp, it works perfectly as well

You may be omitting  secure canvas url section

[image]

Comment: Thanks moguzalp, the problem is in the "App Domain" in basic info section. I need to set this to localhost - something I could do before. Now it just ignores it. It is needed when I use the graph api and to some redirects and so.

Answer (score 2):

You could add an entry in your host file like this...

127.0.0.1   debugging.myfacebookapp.com

Then you can set your 'App Domain' to 'debugging.myfacebookapp.com' which is essentially localhost... Simples :)

Answer (score 0):

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/14142088/443359

You don't need to do anything special. Just set `App Domains` to `localhost` and `Website with Facebook Login` to `http://localhost:3000`