# How to handle OmniAuth callbacks in multiple environments?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, facebook, omniauth

I have an app that uses Facebook exclusively as a provider for authentication and have correctly setup the callback for production mode. In order for this to work, you provide your Facebook app with a site URL and a site domain for callbacks, and in my case it's `http://appname.heroku.com` and `appname.heroku.com` respectively.

The problem is that my controllers are setup to only allow authenticated sessions so I cannot view my app in development mode because the Facebook app's domain obviously hasn't been set to localhost.

How do I get around this without having to change it in Facebook's settings?

Comment: create another facebook app for development with domain localhost:3000

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Create another one facebook app with domain `localhost:3000` for development and create
`config.yml` in the `config` directory

```
development:
  facebook_api_key: 656756786867868
  facebook_api_secret: 4sdffdh6u345436

production:
  facebook_api_key: 45778799
  facebook_api_secret: fghjkbbcbcbcbcb
```

Now add load_config.rb to the initializers folder

```
# load config
AppConfig = YAML.load_file(Rails.root.join('config', 'config.yml'))

# Override config options by correct environment
env_options = AppConfig.delete(Rails.env)

AppConfig.merge!(env_options) unless env_options.nil?
```

And finally add this to the `omniauth.rb`

```
Rails.application.config.middleware.use OmniAuth::Builder do
   provider :facebook, AppConfig['facebook_api_key'], AppConfig['facebook_api_secret']           
end
```

It will take your keys depending on rails environment. That's all, hope it helps you.

Comment: Quite an obvious solution. Thanks

Comment: By the way, the domain can't be localhost:3000 because Facebook won't accept that. The URL should be http://localhost:3000 and the domain is localhost.local with my hosts file set to 127.0.0.1 localhost.local

Comment: I have couple of development apps with host `http://localhost:3000/` and domain `localhost`. All works just fine

Comment: Wonder why Facebook wouldn't let me use localhost - not the only one with the problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7862974/is-localhost-not-saved-anymore-in-app-domain

Comment: Maybe you dont have dedicated IP, dunno

Comment: What's with the delete and re-merge?  Why wouldn't you just do provider :facebook, AppConfig[Rails.env]['facebook_api_key'], AppConfig[Rails.env]['facebook_api_secret']

Comment: Well i don't want to use extra param for my config variables across the whole app.

Answer (score 10):

Why not just create ENV[] variables in the environments files and using them like this in your initializer:

```
provider :facebook, ENV['FACEBOOK_KEY'], ENV['FACEBOOK']
provider :twitter, ENV['TWITTER_KEY'], ENV['TWITTER_SECRET']
```

It seems much easier (and shorter) to me.

Comment: Yes, but i dont like this solution, it just doesnt `clean` enough for me.

Comment: This is more secure than having your keys in a text file that you upload to the server.

Comment: This is a nice solution so your passwords aren't stored in version control. [Heroku](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/config-vars) makes this easy too: `heroku config:add FACEBOOK_KEY=abc123xyz`