# Facebook One or more of the given URLs is not allowed by the App's settings

Tags: facebook, facebook-apps, facebook-authentication, blogspot

Result in console:

> Given URL is not allowed by the Application configuration.: One or more of the given URLs is not allowed by the App's settings.  It must match the Website URL or Canvas URL, or the domain must be a subdomain of one of the App's domains.

Basically what I am trying is to enable user to login on my blog on blogspot.com, and to post on his wall some message.

here is how I configure app on facebook:
**App Domains**:blogspot.com 
**Sandbox Mode**:disabled 
**Site URL**:my_blog_name.blogspot.com/p/publishing.html

Answer (score 8, accepted):

after putting **site url** to begin with **http://** it resolve my issue.
Now my **Site URL** looks like this: http://my_blog_name.blogspot.com/p/publishing.html

Comment: Yes, the protocol identifier is necessary here, you had ommitted it in your original question

Comment: I did same as you said above. In https://developers.facebook.com/apps/myappid/summary?ref=nav ,here i have mention "example.networks.com" in "App Domains" , and "Website with Facebook Login" - Site URL: is "http://example.networks.com"(and also i tried with http://example.networks.com/facebookEX4.htm) . And my html page in which I am calling FB.getLoginStatus is placed at http://example.networks.com/facebookEX4.htm. But still I am gettting same error. Could you tell me what i am missing still ?

Comment: Both, Site URL & App Domain contribute to the allowed callback and origin. Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/a/7493806/614825 which is still relevant as of today.

Answer (score 8):

This can also happen when the `redirect_uri` submitted with the https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth request is not present in the list of **Valid OAuth redirect URIs** under:

- Settings >> Advanced >> Security

After much trial and error, when I added the `redirect_uri` that I was using (https://www.facebook.com/connect/login_success.html in my case), I suddenly got to the step past this error.

Comment: This solved that problem for me: when changing the domain of a site it's easy to miss this setting...

Comment: This has moved now (advanced/Client OAuth Settings) but is very important! Worth noting this _didn't_ work for me with `https://` and only kicked into life when switching to `http://`.

Comment: This has moved now (advanced/Client OAuth Settings) .

Answer (score 3):

These Problem Occurs Because of You Are not correctly  Configure Your Site Link in FaceBook.

Go  Facebook Developers page

1.Select 'Settings'
2.Click 'ADD PlatForm'
3.Select 'Wesite'
4.Give Your Website Name

Finally Save  the Settings That's All

Answer (score 2):

Facebook doesn't care what actual IP address your server is located at - but it will check that the domain name of the referring page is the same as the domain you registered with facebook.The problem is that whatever url you are currently hosting your app is not setup in your Application configuration. Go to your app settings and ensure the urls are matching.

Answer (score 1):

In my case it was the www. that I omitted, so for instance:

**`http://website.com`**

instead of

**`http://www.website.com`**

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem because at first I didn't put app domain in the **Settings** page. And after I added "example.com" to the app domain field (assume URL is http://www.example.com), the problem no longer exists.

Answer (score 0):

If it does'nt work even after you have setup the website URL in **Settings -> Basic tab**, and **Settings -> Advanced -> Valid OAuth redirect URIs**, Try doing the following stuff and check if it works out.

Step 1) 
Goto, **Settings -> Basic -> Contact Email** (Fill the email id you want your app to sync with)

Step 2) Goto, **Status & Review -> Status -> Enable options as yes** (Make your app visible to public)

Now, restart your app and check, if it works fine..

Answer (score 0):

Your application should be on the same domain of what you enter in the facebook developper's settings

Answer (score 0):

## Facebook App Settings

Although answered several times with similar info, this is my experience FYI

- Testing on `localhost` - I wondered if that might be the problem, but nope.
- `app_id` and `redirect_uri` included.
- URLs properly encoded.

So why this error?

See [Facebook Community Help](https://www.facebook.com/help/community/question/?id=542958419109491) as I did, for the important missing part of the puzzle.

That is:

```
<a href="https://www.facebook.com/dialog/share?
    app_id=1234567890
    &display=page

    &href=http%3A%2F%2Fexample.org <-- This
    &redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Fexample.org" <-- and This

target="_overTheRainbow">Tell the world about this awesomeness!</a>
```

Must match the reference URLs submitted to Facebook for the app with `app_id`.

Answer (score 0):

Yes This is The common problem of facebook api. Don't use **www** before url. It will solve the problem.

Answer (score -1):

I was facing same problem when I was posting links on Facebook wall.

I did this:

From https://developers.facebook.com/

On **Migration** tab **Stream post URL security** was enabled. So I just disabled it and after that it is working for me now.

Hope this solve the problem for others.

Answer (score -1):

Go to settings and and then Advanced tab. At the bottom "Embedded browser OAuth Login" enable this option. then your problem is resolved.