# Facebook login: how to configure for access from more than one domain (at least for development)

Tags: facebook, facebook-login

I would like to be able to have my login work in development mode (localhost:3000) as well as on the production server, and ideally, on a staging server.

Apparently you can only configure one domain for login, unlike Google apps, which is much smarter.

Maybe I could rig up my hosts file to do something spiffy with a subdomain?

Answer (score 0):

Under Basic Info: App Domains, you can put in your domain. It will handle all subdomains if you just put in the main domain name: '<yourdomain>.com' So it will definitely be able to handle your dev.yourdomain.com, qa.yourdomain.com, staging.yourdomain.com, etc.

As for your local development, that's where it gets tricky. You can't use multiple domains, as you've noted. You can definitely try to follow this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7493806/183880 which involves creating a second Facebook app and configuring the domain to localhost.

I'm not sure if anyone else has solved it yet, but I came across the problem where if you are trying to develop Open Graph actions and objects, it's pretty much difficult if not impossible to develop those locally. This is because the Facebook servers need to be able to access the Open Graph object urls. And in this case since you'll be developing locally, they can't access `http://localhost:3000/my-object-url.` Somehow you need to be able to expose your local environment to the external world. More trouble than it's worth, in my opinon. My only work around is to just deploy to a development server `http://dev.yourdomain.com` and test from there.

Comment: I ended up just creating a separate FB app that I'll use for dev environment.