# JSF+Facebook Integration One or more of the given URLs is not allowed by the App's settings. It must match the Website URL or Canvas URL

Tags: java, facebook, jsf, canvas

I have created a Facebook Application and details are given screen shot !

[image]

[image]

[image]

But when i am clicking on JSF Button Login with Facebook I am getting below exception

> Given URL is not allowed by the Application configuration.: One or
>   more of the given URLs is not allowed by the App's settings. It must
>   match the Website URL or Canvas URL, or the domain must be a subdomain
>   of one of the App's domains.

Here are code i am using for redirect

```
private void redirect(String url, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws IOException {

        String urlSessionID = response.encodeRedirectURL(url);
        response.sendRedirect(urlSessionID);

    }
```

I tried other solution provided in other question which i found in Stackoverflow but its not worked for me .

```
if (requestUrl.indexOf("Login.xhtml") > 0) {
            callback = requestUrl.replaceAll("Login.xhtml", "fblogin.xhtml");
        } else if (requestUrl.indexOf("UserRegistration.xhtml") > 0) {
            callback = requestUrl.replaceAll("UserRegistration.xhtml",
                    "fblogin.xhtml");
        }
        service = new ServiceBuilder().provider(FacebookApi.class)
                .apiKey(apiKey).apiSecret(apiSecret).callback(callback)
                .scope("email,offline_access").build();
```

Comment: Which url are you redirecting to?

Comment: Added more screen shot

Comment: That just shows the settings. Not what you actually redirecting to

Comment: May be i am not able to understand but i am redirecting to http://192.168.11.7:8080/3c/login/fblogin.xhtml

Comment: Ok, my guess is that internal ip addresses are not allowed

Comment: I tried with localhost as well i got same issue

Comment: localhost is also an internal address. Change it to anything.com and then add that domain in your hosts file and point it to your local webserver and see if that works

Comment: So you mean i have to add doamin something like this mywebsite.com in tomcat server.xml file

Comment: I don't know how you would configure tomcat

Comment: But see this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4532721/facebook-development-in-localhost

Comment: If localhost works you are doing something wrong

Comment: Hmm that i want to know whats going on wrong

Comment: I would remove Valid OAuth redirects URLs. And if that doesn't work my guess is that you are redirecting to some other url than you think

Comment: thanks @WizKid it is working for only that user who created application

Comment: Have you taken the app live?

Comment: thats is coming disable i am trying to enable yes but nothing working

Comment: If you hover over the live button there should be a tool tip saying what you need to do to take it live

Comment: Issue is that i did not added "Contact Email" in Settings->Basic

Comment: @WizKid Sorry but do you know anything abt servlet3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made changes in the application and it worked but only for the user who created application not for other user

[image]