# Microsoft MVC 5 Authentication not working

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, authentication, oauth-2.0, asp.net-authentication

I'm having some problems with out of the box Microsoft Authentication with a plain MVC 5 site.

I have set up my hosts file to route 127.0.0.1 to www.mysite.com.

I have configured the redirect url for the App on windows live to goto www.mysite.com/signin-microsoft

In Visual Studio 2015 I've set the properties for the website to use Local IIS and www.mysite.com

When I try to authenticate through Microsoft, it shows the Live login screen, when I enter my details it redirects back to the account controller endpoint ExternalLoginCallback(string returnUrl)
but - returnUrl is null and the next line where it tries to get loginInfo always returns null.

Auth is set up in Startup.Auth 
as

```
var options = new MicrosoftAccountAuthenticationOptions
            {
                ClientId = "<redacted>",
                ClientSecret = "<redacted>",
                CallbackPath = new PathString("/signin-microsoft")

        };
options.Scope.Add(scope);

        app.UseMicrosoftAccountAuthentication(options);
```

I hit this url in fiddler - "Account/ExternalLoginCallback?error=access_denied"

I've followed the answer in this post - [ASP.NET MVC Microsoft Live Account Authentication on Localhost](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25049480/asp-net-mvc-microsoft-live-account-authentication-on-localhost)

I can't work out what I'm missing.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: What is "Microsoft Authentication"? Doesn't the callback site need to be publicly accessible for third-party authentication to work?

Comment: OAuth using Microsoft as a provider. Basically using the "UseMicrosoftAccountAuthentication" section in Startup.Auth.cs. From what I've read you can spoof it in dev using the hosts file...

Comment: Did you check if your callback address is configured in your Microsoft application?

Comment: Yep - redirectUrl is set to be www.mysite.com/signin-microsoft

Comment: Try to disable the option Restrict JWT Issuing.

Comment: Disabling Restrict JWT Issuing gives the same issue. AuthenticationManager.GetExternalLoginInfoAsync() always returns null - I don't see the Live login screen.

Answer (score 1):

You may get a clue of what is wrong by turning on the tracing for your OWIN middleware in the web.config of your project:

```
<configuration>
  <system.diagnostics>
    <switches>
      <add name="Microsoft.Owin" value="Verbose" />
    </switches>
  </system.diagnostics>
</configuration>
```

The output will by default appear in your debug console window, but you can change this by adding trace listeners. For more information about OWIN logging see [this article](http://www.tugberkugurlu.com/archive/logging-in-the-owin-world-with-microsoft-owin--introduction).

Comment: Thanks - I'll try that