# How to serve a very simple, raw, Ember.js application?

Tags: javascript, ember.js, nginx

I believe this can be considered a very silly question, but I'm really stuck on it for some time. I have a very simple Ember.js application (that means I am **not** using Ember-CLI) and since I am using the Facebook SDK in it, I need a valid domain.

Until now, I've ran my app simply by double clicking the `index.html` file in the browser.

Then, in order to have a domain for my app, I've tried using nginx inside a Docker container (so that I can add the `http://<docker-ip>` URL in my Facebook settings). The problem was that nginx (with the default configurations from the official Docker image) was somewhat loading a stale version of both JS files and `index.html`, even though the container had the *latest* versions of the files. I've even tried destroying the container, then starting it again and the issue persisted.

I've then tried looking at other approaches, but none satisfied my need of something simple:

- node.js server, too much for serving a very basic app;
- middleman, too much setup because I don't need to compile stuff (no .hbs, no less etc.);
- ember-cli server, doesn't work with a normal Ember.js app;
- other small JS servers, had to configure them too much for just serving some static files;
- GitHub Pages and S3 **do** work, but...I don't want to deploy each time when developing.

So, please help me in this silly quest, how can I serve a basic Ember.js app (preferably from a Docker container)?

Comment: You can try it in localhost. [Facebook development in localhost](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4532721/2429040)

Comment: I was asking **how** can I serve an app on my local machine, with/by what...

Comment: I tried to say that Facebook SDK gives you the opportunity to test your app   in development environment. So you can test it in localhost no need any domain name, unless you want to test it in production environment.

Comment: I understand, but in order to see the app on localhost you need to do something, and that is my question.

Comment: Oh, you can try Apache server using [xampp](https://www.apachefriends.org/index.html). It is very easy to use. After installing xampp, put your `index.html` inside `htdocs` folder and start apache from xampp control panel and browse `localhost/index.html`. I think this will work for you.

Comment: I will try then using Apache with Docker. But any idea why Nginx didn't work?