# How to setup local to set and get token for OAuth

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, dotnetopenauth, oauth-2.0

I have not used OAuth before and I don’t know where to start.

I need to get access token from from specific token provide/server, something like google+ but privately owned, but the issue is that cannot return back to http://localhost/myapp.

So I need two things if you please help me

(1) Is there any option I can setup application within my dev which returns access token?
(2) How to fetch/get token? Is there any example?

I have tried googling it but did not get success or I am not understanding OAuth techno. Prefer to use DotNetOpenAuth if possible.

Comment: I can help you with OAuth bearer token

Comment: Will be good if you please help me Karthik.

Comment: @KarthikMR please help me. Let me know if you want me to call you.

Comment: Linked [as duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4536922/477420) answer provides answer to your immediate question. For guides/tutorials make make sure to search yourself.

Comment: check out this youtube video - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vqwjnl13Whc