# Laravel Socialite Facebook login using artisan serve on local machine

Tags: php, laravel, facebook-login, laravel-artisan

I'm trying to test a Facebook login on my local machine using artisan server to test. I've setup a Facebook app and Socialite as per instructions but i get an error from Facebook about having to use HTTPS only.

I have read the documentation and am aware that from March this year they set HTTPS as default but the option is disabled so i have no way of turning this off.

My question is, is there any way of testing this on my local machine?

Comment: please read this https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: This is not a development question, please read the link above, and perform a search before posting : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4532721/facebook-development-in-localhost